# Operation matrix with condition

Tags: python, matrix

Please help me. I have some upper bound and lower bound matrices then I compute the matrices A(p), B(pu) and C(u) with p=1,..., rows_a and u=1,...,column_c and I operate them to find X for each p and u.
I've tried like this

```
    import numpy as np
rows_a = int(input("Enter the number of rows of matrix A : " ))
column_a = int(input("Enter the number of columns of matrix A : "))

print("Input elements of the lower bound matrix  A:")
lowerboundA= [[float(input())  for i in range(column_a)] for j in range(rows_a)]

print("Input elements of the upper bound matrix  A:")
upperboundA= [[float(input())  for i in range(column_a)] for j in range(rows_a)]
    
#Determining the Matrix A(p) 
ubA= np.array(upperboundA)
lbA= np.array(lowerboundA)
def entry(matrixM, matrixN, i):
    i = i - 1     
    matrixA = matrixN.copy()
    matrixA[i]= matrixM[i]
    return matrixA
    
A1 = entry( lbA,ubA, 1)
print("Matrix A(1)=: ")
for n in A1:
    print(n)

A1transpose =[[0 for i in range(rows_a)] for j in range(column_a)]

for f in range(rows_a):
   
   for g in range(column_a):
    A1transpose[g][f] = A1[f][g]

rows_c = int(input("Enter the number of rows of matrix C : " ))
column_c = int(input("Enter the number of columns of matrix C: "))

print("Input elements of the lower bound matrix C:")

lowerboundC= [[float(input()) for i in range(column_c)] for j in range(rows_c)]
    
print("Input elements of the upper bound matrix C:")

upperboundC= [[float(input()) for i in range(column_c)] for j in range(rows_c)]
    
#Determining the Matrix C(u) 
ubC= np.array(upperboundC)
lbC= np.array(lowerboundC)
def entry(matrixM, matrixN, j):
    j = j - 1       
    matrixC = matrixN.copy()
    matrixC[:,j]= matrixM[:,j]
    return matrixC
    
C1 = entry( lbC,ubC, 1)
print("Matrix C(1)=: ")
for n in C1:
    print(n)

C1transpose =[[0 for i in range(rows_c)] for j in range(column_c)]
for d in range(rows_c):
    
   for e in range(column_c):
    C1transpose[e][d] = C1[d][e]

print("Input elements of the lower bound matrix B:")

lowerboundB= [[float(input()) for i in range(column_c)] for j in range(rows_a)]
   
print("Input elements of the upper bound matrix B:")

upperboundB= [[float(input()) for i in range(column_c)] for j in range(rows_a)]
    
#Determining the Matrix B(pu)
ubB= np.array(upperboundB)
lbB= np.array(lowerboundB)
def entry(matrixM, matrixN, i, j):
    i = i - 1
    j = j - 1       
    matrixB = matrixN.copy()
    matrixB[i][j] = matrixM[i][j]
    return matrixB
    
B11 = entry(ubB, lbB, 1, 1)
print("Matrix B(11)=: ")
for n in B11:
    print(n)
#Determining X*(A(1),B(11)
XAb = [[min(-a+b for a, b in zip(column_a , rows_c)) 
                        for rows_c  in zip(*B11)]
                                for column_a in A1transpose]
print("\nX(A,b) is: ") 
for xab in XAb:
    print(xab)
    
   
#Determining X*(A(1),B(11),C(1)    
X = [[min(-a+b for b,a in zip(rows_c , column_a)) 
                        for column_a  in zip(*C1transpose)]
                                for rows_c in XAb] 
print("\nX(A,b,c) is: ") 
for x in X:
    print(x)
```

in the code above I can only calculate A(p), B(pu) and C(u) for p=1 and u=1. How do I calculate A(p), B(pu) and C(u) for each p and u with p=1,..., rows_a and u=1,...,column_c ?

Comment: `A(1)transpose =[[0 for i in range(rows_a)] for j in range(column_a)]` -- That's a syntax error.  It can't be your real code.

Comment: Did you derive this from a Matlab script?

Comment: I'm using python. Sorry, I have edited the codes

Comment: I can see you're using Python.  Did this start from a Matlab script?

Comment: Not, is it still error? I I've updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you ask.  Notice that I have re-organized the code to put all of the input stuff in front, so that the p/u dependent stuff is at the end.  Note that I may have misunderstood the relationship between the size of the A and C matrices and the size of the B matrix, so check this carefully.

Note that numpy includes a transpose routine.  You don't need to do it by hand.  I haven't decomposed the computation of `Xab` amd `X` to see if those could use numpy primitives, but I wouldn't be surprised.

```
import numpy as np

rows_a = int(input("Enter the number of rows of matrix A : " ))
column_a = int(input("Enter the number of columns of matrix A : "))

print("Input elements of the lower bound matrix  A:")
lowerboundA= [[float(input())  for i in range(column_a)] for j in range(rows_a)]

print("Input elements of the upper bound matrix  A:")
upperboundA= [[float(input())  for i in range(column_a)] for j in range(rows_a)]

rows_c = int(input("Enter the number of rows of matrix C : " ))
column_c = int(input("Enter the number of columns of matrix C: "))

print("Input elements of the lower bound matrix C:")
lowerboundC= [[float(input()) for i in range(column_c)] for j in range(rows_c)]
    
print("Input elements of the upper bound matrix C:")
upperboundC= [[float(input()) for i in range(column_c)] for j in range(rows_c)]

print("Input elements of the lower bound matrix B:")
lowerboundB= [[float(input()) for i in range(column_c)] for j in range(rows_a)]
   
print("Input elements of the upper bound matrix B:")
upperboundB= [[float(input()) for i in range(column_c)] for j in range(rows_a)]

## That's all the input.

ubA = np.array(upperboundA)
lbA = np.array(lowerboundA)
ubC = np.array(upperboundC)
lbC = np.array(lowerboundC)
ubB = np.array(upperboundB)
lbB = np.array(lowerboundB)

def entry0(matrixM, matrixN, i):
    matrixA = matrixN.copy()
    matrixA[i]= matrixM[i]
    return matrixA
def entry1(matrixM, matrixN, j):
    matrixC = matrixN.copy()
    matrixC[:,j]= matrixM[:,j]
    return matrixC
def entry2(matrixM, matrixN, i, j):
    matrixB = matrixN.copy()
    matrixB[i][j] = matrixM[i][j]
    return matrixB

for p in range(lbA.shape[0]):
    for u in range(lbC.shape[0]):
        print( f"\n*****\np = {p+1}, u = {u+1}\n*****" )
            
#Determining the Matrix A(p) 
            
        A1T = entry0( lbA,ubA, p).transpose()
        print("Matrix A(1)=: ")
        print(A1T)
            
#Determining the Matrix C(u) 
            
        C1T = entry1( lbC,ubC, u).transpose()
        print("Matrix C(1)=: ")
        print(C1T)

#Determining the Matrix B(pu)
            
        B11 = entry2(ubB, lbB, p, u)
        print("Matrix B(11)=: ")
        print(B11)

#Determining X*(A(1),B(11)

        XAb = np.array([[min(-a+b for a, b in zip(column_a , rows_c)) 
                    for rows_c  in zip(*B11)]
                            for column_a in A1T])
        print("\nX(A,b) is: ") 
        print(XAb)
            
           
#Determining X*(A(1),B(11),C(1)

        X = np.array([[min(-a+b for b,a in zip(rows_c , column_a)) 
                    for column_a  in zip(*C1T)]
                            for rows_c in XAb])
        print("\nX(A,b,c) is: ") 
        print(X)
```

Comment: Why for p in range(lbA.shape[0]):
    for u in range(lbC.shape[0]): ?? I mean that for p in range(rows_a):
    for u in range(column_c).  Thank you very much, your answers are very helpful

Comment: I actually changed that in my own code after I posted the answer, but the end result is the same, right?  Those array bounds comes from the row/column values.  Also, you are changing `rows_c` and `column_a` when you create X and XAb, which is probably a bug.

Comment: Sorry, I have problem when I make conclusion with if (np.allclose(AXC,Bpu)==True):
  print("matrices are equivalent");  
else:
  print("matrices are not equivalent");  I cannot find AXC=Bpu for each p and u.. just for one p and u. why? can you help me?

Comment: Since `AXC` and `Bpu` are not present in any of the code here, your question doesn't make any sense.  You need to ask a new question with your code as it currently stands.